# identify the type/Kind document

Tags: java, ocr, document

My basic requirement is that I have the text document which is generated from OCR tool and now I want to identify which type of document is this. Passport, driving license, bank statement, S.S.N. /Aadhar, programmatically through java. Any pointer/starter would help. Thanks

Comment: Requests for recommendations are off-topic at SO. However, you could look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What is needed: content parsing for keywords with "fuzzy search" or "wild character" to accommodate possible errors from OCR.  These documents are tough and are sure to contain OCR mistakes due to backgrounds, etc.  Search for more than one keyword for redundancy and more tolerant classificaiotn.

How: many online sources.  I suggest starting with generic research for "text parsing".